# Possible drive failure? BSOD on Windows Loading screen -> Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid

I've got a rig running Windows Server 2008 R2 with 2 1TB drives in it. I believe they were in a RAID 1 Software array.

Recently I went to restart the computer, and on startup it BSOD when the loading windows screen appeared.

No idea where to start as I can't even get into Windows (or safe mode). Tried auto repair (to no avail)
I've chucked the drives into another machine so I've narrowed it down to the drives. 
It is possible that one of the drives has failed but I can't work out which one. And what's more, even when I try to boot off 1 (ive tried each by themselves) it still BSOD on windows loading screen. So I can't get in and repair the array.

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated.

Comment: Restore from your last known good backup to known good disks.

Comment: Ive only got a backup of the database, not the full server. Would like to fix server if possible. Otherwise ill have to reinstall and restore DB.

Comment: `I believe they were in a RAID 1 Software array` - How could you not know for sure? `I've chucked the drives into another machine so I've narrowed it down to the drives` - How did that action allow you to narrow the problem down to the drives? `it still BSOD on windows loading screen` - What is the BSOD? Have you attempted to troubleshoot the BSOD?

Comment: `Ive only got a backup of the database, not the full server.` I see.  And what have we learned from this?

Comment: If the disks were in a raid 1 array, then each disk will work independently. Since you can boot but get BSOD, you don't have a booting issue, nor a raid issue. Rebuilding the array is a problem for after you have booted and its simple. It sounds like a driver issue but you've supplied little or no information. You need to say what error you are getting. Theres a reason why Error codes are displayed when windows bugchecks.

Comment: @IanMurphy `VOLMGRX_INTERNAL_ERROR`  `*** STOP: 0x00000058`  Thats the info on the BSOD. I haven't installed any new hardware...

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see your response until now. That error indicates that one of the shadow members is inconsistent with the other. The only solution is going to be to take one or the other disks and try and get it to boot alone. You may need to use partition repair tools to achieve this.